# Securing a client-side Java application

Tags: java, security

Recently I've been developing a client-side Java Swing application for a client, and I've had a creeping concern that at any given time the client could simply take a snapshot build of the system and run-off with it.

The app needs to be connected to the internet in order to do anything, and I was hoping on getting some tips on how I could put some sort of security in-place to prevent the system from working if I wanted to  i.e. he may copy/install the application somewhere else without me knowing about it (edit from the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616125/securing-a-client-side-java-application#comment6398714_5616174)).

I'd need this to be fairly transparent to the client, and it wouldn't need to be 100% robust as the client is not technically competent and is unlikely to try to 'crack' any security that is there.

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you afraid that he's going to steal the app or steal the source code?

Comment: I've always found these books good: http://www.hackingexposedjava.com/

Comment: if your application only makes sense when there's Internet access and if your client is OK with your application performing a *"licence check"*, then there's a foolproof and **impossible to crak** easy way to solve your problem: make some part of you application's computation happen on the server-side.  This is provable **impossible** to crack.  The only way to "crack" this is to rewrite the part of the computation that happens on the server side.  This is used daily by a **lot** of software that have never and will never be cracked.

Comment: take this example: there isn't a **single** player playing in the real World of Warcraft economy (that is: on the real Blizzard servers) with a "cracked" version of World of Warcraft.  Because there's no such thing: server side protection, when done correctly, means *"good game pirates"*.

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r thanks for the tip that's a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want to look into code obfuscation:

http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~collberg/Research/Students/DouglasLow/obfuscation.html

http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators

Comment: Not really worried he's going to steal the source, I'm just worried he might take a copy of the app and run it somewhere else without me knowing. I guess what I'd need is basically a way to turn off access to the app wherever it is being run.